# How to wrap html code by condition in vue without duplication code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Assume I want to wrap some html code in div. I can write

```
<template>
  <div v-if="condition == true">
    //a lot of html
  </div>
  <template v-else>
    //a lot of html
  </template>
</template>
```

But then I have to duplicate "a lot of html" block. Also I can extract `a lot of html block` in another component, but logically it's already separated component. Is there any way?

P.S. In this topic I just simplified my case. I actually need to set two modes of rendering component by condition. First is div with some content inside, second is this div wrapped in table's cell with controls in another cells.

Comment: An extra div doesn't normally do much. Can you leave it in place unconditionally, but toggle a CSS class using Vue instead?

Comment: I actually don't need to wrap it in div but in cell of table. It's not for css.

Comment: why not `<template>
  <div><div v-if="condition == true">other html</div>
    <table>
      //a lot of html
    </table>
  </div>
</template>`

Comment: Because `a lot of html` is always wrapped, not by condition. In this question I just simplified my case. I actually need to set two modes of rendering component by condition. First is div with some content inside, second is this div wrapped in table's cell with controls in another cells.

Comment: Well, you can just extract a lot of html into a new component